# Upgrade docker compose file from traefik v1 to traefik v2

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, traefik

I am currently experimenting with docker swarm in combination with pihole and traefik. My problem is that I am not successful upgrading traefik v1.7.30 to v2.6.1. Does anybody know the correct labels for docker-compose? I was searching on the official documentation but didn't found a configuration for docker-compose.

```
version: "3"
services:

  pihole:
    image: pihole/pihole:latest
    deploy:
      replicas: 3
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        max_attempts: 3
      labels:
        - 'traefik.docker.network=pihole_pihole'
        - 'traefik.port=80'
        - 'traefik.frontend.rule=PathPrefix:/'
        - 'traefik.backend.loadbalancer.stickiness=true'
        - 'traefik.enable=true'
    volumes:
      - pihole:/etc/pihole
      - pihole_dnsmasq:/etc/dnsmasq.d
    ports:
      - "53:53/tcp"
      - "53:53/udp"
      - "67:67/udp"
    networks:
      - pihole

    environment:
      - TZ='Europe/Berlin'
      - WEBPASSWORD=<your-password>
      - FTL_CMD=debug
      - DNSMASQ_LISTENING=all
    dns:
      - 127.0.0.1
      - 1.1.1.1
      - 8.8.8.8


  traefik:
    image: traefik:v1.7.30
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [ node.role==manager ]
    command:
      --docker \
      --docker.swarmmode \
      --docker.watch --web --loglevel=DEBUG
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "9090:8080"
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
    networks:
      - default
      - pihole


volumes:
  pihole:
  pihole_dnsmasq:

networks:
  pihole:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I successfully managed to upgrade to traefik v2. This is the end result:

```
version: "3"
services:

  pihole:
    image: pihole/pihole:latest
    deploy:
      replicas: 3
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        max_attempts: 3
      labels:
        - traefik.enable=true
        - traefik.docker.network=pihole_pihole
        - traefik.http.routers.pihole.entrypoints=web
        - traefik.http.routers.pihole.rule=PathPrefix("/")
        - traefik.http.services.pihole.loadbalancer.server.port=80
        - traefik.http.services.pihole.loadbalancer.sticky=true
        - traefik.http.services.pihole.loadbalancer.sticky.cookie.name=StickyCookie
    volumes:
      - pihole:/etc/pihole
      - pihole_dnsmasq:/etc/dnsmasq.d
    ports:
      - "53:53/tcp"
      - "53:53/udp"
      - "67:67/udp"
    networks:
      - pihole

    environment:
      - TZ='Europe/Berlin'
      - WEBPASSWORD=<your-password>
      - FTL_CMD=debug
      - DNSMASQ_LISTENING=all
    dns:
      - 127.0.0.1
      - 1.1.1.1
      - 8.8.8.8


  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.6.1
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [ node.role==manager ]
    command:
      - --log.level=DEBUG
      - --api.insecure=true
      - --ping=true
      - --entrypoints.web.address=:80
      - --providers.docker.swarmmode=true
      - --providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false
      - --providers.docker.network=pihole_pihole
      - --providers.docker.watch=true
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "9090:8080"
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
    networks:
      - default
      - pihole


volumes:
  pihole:
  pihole_dnsmasq:

networks:
  pihole:
```